# Limits, tangents and areas. Why are these statements intuitive?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry

I'm reading *Calculus: Early Transcendentals*, by Anton, Bivens and Davis (9th edition). I'm not understanding a few things. Could someone please help me?

On page 68 it says: "suppose that we are interested in the tangent line at a point P on a curve in the xy-plane and that Q is any point that lies on the curve and is different from P. The line through P and Q is called a secant line for the curve at P. **Intuition suggests that if we move the point Q along the curve toward P, then the secant line will rotate toward a limiting position**. The line in this limiting position is what we will consider to be the tangent line at P" *(the bold is mine)*

My intuition doesn't suggest this... Even if I imagine a curve like a circle, I don't get why there should be a limiting position... Or if I think like this: let's think in parts: 1) moving only the vertical coordinate of Q towards that of P contributes to a rotation in one direction, and it's obvious there is a limiting position if of moves only the vertical coordinate... 2) moving only the horizontal coordinate of Q towards that of P contributes to a rotation in an opposite direction to that, and it's obvious there is a limiting position if one moves only the horizontal coordinate... **But** it's not obvious to me that if we move both the coordinates there is going to be a limiting position. And I'm thinking only about circles, let alone curves in general.

On page 69 it says: "For plane regions with straight-line boundaries, areas can often be calculated by subdividing the region into rectangles or triangles and adding the areas of the constituent parts (Figure 1.1.6). However, for regions with curved boundaries, such as that in Figure 1.1.7a, a more general approach is needed. One such approach is to begin by approximating the area of the region by inscribing a number of rectangles of equal width under the curve and adding the areas of these rectangles (Figure 1.1.7b). **Intuition suggests that if we repeat that approximation process using more and more rectangles, then the rectangles will tend to fill in the gaps under the curve, and the approximations will get closer and closer to the exact area under the curve** (Figure 1.1.7c). This suggests that we can define the area under the curve to be the limiting value of these approximations" *(the bold is mine)*

Again, this is not intuitive to me... I get that it will never surpass the exact area, because they are all inside... **But**, is it really true that always that one increases the number of inscribed rectangles the approximation will improve? For example, to me it seems that sometimes one can get a higher number of rectangles that gives the same area as a lesser number of them... Is it possible to prove that statement in bold letters in the quote?

Comment: Even in the seventeenth century, this second statement was not considered obvious. Newton gave a proof for a special case of it in the Principia (not rigorous by modern standards, but very convincing): http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/analysis/integral/integralCota.html